# Select last record of every hour, but time is not precise

Tags: mysql, mariadb, select

I have table in MariaDB like this

```
INSERT INTO `electric_meters` (`id`, `ts`, `id_sensor`, `value`) VALUES
(166063,    '2024-02-16 07:00:00.625',  'ats01_TotalCounter',   8801.936),
(166043,    '2024-02-16 06:45:01.008',  'ats01_TotalCounter',   8791.536),
(166021,    '2024-02-16 06:30:00.985',  'ats01_TotalCounter',   8781.552),
(166000,    '2024-02-16 06:15:00.800',  'ats01_TotalCounter',   8771.568),
(165979,    '2024-02-16 05:59:58.365',  'ats01_TotalCounter',   8761.168),
(165961,    '2024-02-16 05:45:01.256',  'ats01_TotalCounter',   8752.016),
(165938,    '2024-02-16 05:30:00.088',  'ats01_TotalCounter',   8743.280),
(165916,    '2024-02-16 05:15:02.090',  'ats01_TotalCounter',   8734.336),
(165895,    '2024-02-16 05:00:00.009',  'ats01_TotalCounter',   8726.016),
(165876,    '2024-02-16 04:45:02.005',  'ats01_TotalCounter',   8718.320),
(165853,    '2024-02-16 04:30:01.950',  'ats01_TotalCounter',   8711.456),
(165832,    '2024-02-16 04:15:00.088',  'ats01_TotalCounter',   8703.136),
(165811,    '2024-02-16 04:00:00.025',  'ats01_TotalCounter',   8696.272),
(165790,    '2024-02-16 03:45:00.089',  'ats01_TotalCounter',   8691.280),
(165769,    '2024-02-16 03:30:01.788',  'ats01_TotalCounter',   8685.872),
(165748,    '2024-02-16 03:15:03.069',  'ats01_TotalCounter',   8680.464),
(165727,    '2024-02-16 02:59:59.009',  'ats01_TotalCounter',   8675.264),
(165706,    '2024-02-16 02:45:00.800',  'ats01_TotalCounter',   8669.024),
(165686,    '2024-02-16 02:30:00.700',  'ats01_TotalCounter',   8664.448),
(165664,    '2024-02-16 02:15:03.090',  'ats01_TotalCounter',   8659.456),
(165643,    '2024-02-16 02:00:04.940',  'ats01_TotalCounter',   8654.672),
(165622,    '2024-02-16 01:44:58.700',  'ats01_TotalCounter',   8650.096);
```

I need to select last record of every hour, which is closest to hour. Problem is, timestamp is sometimes slightly before (like ID 165979 - 05:59:58.365) and sometimes slightly after (like ID 166063 - 07:00:00.625). Of course, I have multiple sensors, this is just an example with one sensor, and I will select by sensor_id and sort by TS. Correct result should include IDs `166063, 165979, 165895, 165811, 165727, 165643`. Is it possible to write this query?

Thank you for your help!

Edit according comment:
I tried simply round hours and minutes:

```
SELECT 
  T.*
FROM electric_meters AS T
JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(`ts`) AS `max_time` FROM electric_meters GROUP BY HOUR(`ts`), DAY(`ts`), YEAR(`ts`)
) AS t
ON (T.`ts` = t.`max_time`)
```

result is

```
id,ts,id_sensor,value
165622,2024-02-16 01:44:58.700,ats01_TotalCounter,"8650.096"
165727,2024-02-16 02:59:59.009,ats01_TotalCounter,"8675.264"
165790,2024-02-16 03:45:00.089,ats01_TotalCounter,"8691.280"
165876,2024-02-16 04:45:02.005,ats01_TotalCounter,"8718.320"
165979,2024-02-16 05:59:58.365,ats01_TotalCounter,"8761.168"
166043,2024-02-16 06:45:01.008,ats01_TotalCounter,"8791.536"
166063,2024-02-16 07:00:00.625,ats01_TotalCounter,"8801.936"
```

Problem is, it picks 7:00 correctly, byt incorrectly 6:45

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: *.. timestamp is sometimes slightly before .. and sometimes slightly after ..* What is max. allowed deviation? for example, not more than 5 minutes.. Or you want the closest value regardless the deviation?

Comment: It depends.. If it is possible and not HW hungry query, I would like to have it as wide as possible, but I can set some limit if it will be easier, like 5 minutes for example. Data comes in 15 minutes interval, but it can change, mainly because of some problems in HW/network ETC... I can't control it...

Answer (score 1):

If window functions are supported in your version, you could try

```sql
select
    `id`, `ts`, `id_sensor`, `value`
from (
    select
        `id`, `ts`, `id_sensor`, `value`,
        row_number() over (
            partition by date_format(date_add(`ts`, interval 30 minute), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
            order by abs(timestampdiff(microsecond, `ts`, date_format(date_add(`ts`, interval 30 minute), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00'))), `ts` desc
        ) as `row_num`
    from
        `electric_meters`
) as `t`
where `t`.`row_num` = 1;
```

Another option could be to add the following generated columns

```sql
alter table `electric_meters` add column `closest_hour` int unsigned as (floor((unix_timestamp(`ts`) + 1800) / 3600) * 3600) stored;
alter table `electric_meters` add column `diff` int unsigned as (abs(unix_timestamp(`ts`) - `closest_hour`) * 1000) stored;
```

The query would be

```sql
select
    `t1`.`id`, `t1`.`ts`, `t1`.`id_sensor`, `t1`.`value`
from
    `electric_meters` as `t1`
    left join `electric_meters` as `t2`
        on `t1`.`closest_hour` = `t2`.`closest_hour`
        and `t1`.`diff` > `t2`.`diff`
where
    `t2`.`diff` is null;
```

The following composite index is needed for this option

```sql
alter table `electric_meters` add index `idx_closest_hour_diff` (`closest_hour`, `diff`);
```

or may be a covering one instead depending on which attributes are selected

```sql
alter table `electric_meters` add index `idx_closest_hour_diff_ts_id_sensor_value` (`closest_hour`, `diff`, `ts`, `id_sensor`, `value`);
```

Comment: This selection fail, when TS is slightly below hour, like `05:59:58`. It picked `07:00:00, 06:45:01, 05:59:58,...`

Comment: @Ajax I've modified the query. Can you take a look?

Comment: It actually works! Will test it more, but looks like slightly slower to execute.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Maybe is suboptimal, but suits my needs...

```
SELECT 
    T.* 
FROM electric_meters AS T
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        MAX(ts) as ts_max,
        DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(ts, INTERVAL 55 MINUTE), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AS ts_rounded
    FROM electric_meters
    GROUP BY ts_rounded
) AS t ON t.ts_max = T.ts
```

Trick is to round time to nearest hour with some safe interval, like 5 minutes. So, if you add 55 minutes to any time and format it as `%H:00:00`, you will get uniform time across whole hour, including 5 minutes before and 5 minutes after. Then, just group and join.

Any other suggestions or observations are welcome!

Comment: Your 55m trick takes care of "nearest".  Then the please where there is some chance of optimization is in [Groupwise-max].  See that tag and [_Groupwise-Max_](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max)